# Swagger Codegen For Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, swagger-codegen, swaggerhub

I have created apis endpoint with Swaggerhub and successfully exported to run with asp.net core. I want to test the same apis with nestjs but i found documenting with openapi but not the other way round; convert yaml to nodejs.Is there a way to generate to nestjs with typescript from OpenAPI3.0 schema?

Comment: This is not available yet.

Answer (score 2):

Swagger Codegen does not offer Nestjs generator at the moment. Here is a related request but no one seems to have found the time to make the contribution yet: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9559

UPDATE: there's PR to add a Nestjs generator in OpenAPI Generator (a community fork of Swagger Codegen)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Swagger-js-codegen](https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen/) can help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Now there seems to be one project, as far as I can see, that can generate Nest.js code from a Swagger / OpenAPI spec file:

It's called **swagger-nestjs-codegen**. See [here on Github](https://github.com/Ryan-Sin/swagger-nestjs-codegen) and [here on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@newko/swagger-nestjs-codegen). I have yet to test it, though.

Comment: Tried this. It does not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found [swagger-nestjs-codegen](https://github.com/Ryan-Sin/swagger-nestjs-codegen), 11 stars, korean comments