# NestJS codegen from Swagger API definition

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-codegen, nestjs-swagger

Does anybody know of a way to automatically generate NestJS typescript code from Swagger?

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: @HosseinHeydari - I want to generate NestJS (Node) controller code from a Swagger API definition file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger Codegen For Nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651497/swagger-codegen-for-nestjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there are no packages that build a Nest server based on a swagger.json file. Would be a cool project though

Answer (score 1):

Just found a project that claims it can generate Nest.js code from a Swagger / OpenAPI spec file:

**swagger-nestjs-codegen** [on Github](https://github.com/Ryan-Sin/swagger-nestjs-codegen) and [on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@newko/swagger-nestjs-codegen)

Did not test it yet, though.